# Hybrid Application with Python GUI with C++ background modules

Tags: c++, python, boost, wxpython

I want to write a hybrid application which uses python as GUI component, and C++ module as background services.

I know how to program with Python, and C++, but I don't find a mature/nice way to make them work together smoothly. Could you guys shed some light on this for me? A good document/tutorial is also very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use [cython](http://cython.org/) for writing glue code between those two worlds, or if I want stronger separation for any reason I like the [ctypes](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#loading-dynamic-link-libraries) approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with using boost, go for [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/). ([Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html))

Otherwise, use the [CPython API](http://docs.python.org/extending/) directly.

With either of these, you can create Python modules (`.pyd`-files) in C++.

---

I have experience with boost python, and I find it very comfortable and easy. The downside is that it causes huge compile times because it relies heavily on template metaprogramming.

Answer (score 0):

Besides boost, there's also SWIG (http://www.swig.org/). SWIG was used for wxPython's C++ bindings. The new version of wxPython will be using SIP, which I think PyQt is also using: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro

Shed-Skin might also be a possibility: http://shed-skin.blogspot.com/